# How to display the process currently holding a semaphore?

Tags: linux, semaphore

In userspace Linux, I have a process blocking on a semaphore, as found by strace. Once the error condition occurs, the blocking is repeatable, so there must be another process that holds the semaphore and did not release it.

Is there a way to know which other process is currently holding the semaphore?

`ipcs` lists the semaphore, so does /proc/sysvipc/sem. Where can I find info on the holding process?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Semaphores aren't mutexes.  You don't "hold" them.  If the process is blocked, that means it's waiting for someone else to do an "up" or "V" operation on it in the future.  There's no kernel tool that will tell you what the future behavior of software will be.

Answer (score 4):

To find the pids associated with the list of Semaphore Arrays listed by `ipcs -s` you can run this:

```
for pid in $( for semid in $( sudo ipcs -s | awk '/0x/{ print $2 }' ); do sudo ipcs -s -i $semid | tail -2 | head -1 | awk '{print $5}'; done | sort -u ); do ps uh -p $pid; done
```

Answer (score 3):

There may be an easier way but you can use the semctl() call with the GETPID cmd.  That should return the process that executed the last semop() call for the semaphore.  This may or may not be your rogue process but it is probably a good hint.

Answer (score 2):

"ipcs -p " can not show the semaphores of the process holding, that must be a bug, or it's a limit because it's hard to show.
You have to query by yourslef.

1. run "ipcs -s" to get all semid
2. for each semid run "ipcs -s -i "
3. for each semnum, to get owner pid,
   if the owner pid is you wish, then show the current semid and semnum.

Note: if the process just read semaphores, then you may cannot get such information via ipcs command.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
ipcs -p
```

Comment: Does not seem to work with semaphore. I can see the key all right, but ipcs -p -s yields no output.